# How-To Auto Discover a WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5

Is there a way to auto discover a specific WCF service in the network? I don't want to config my client with the address if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to look at is the WS-Discovery protocol.  I found a sample on [netfx3's](http://wcf.netfx3.com/files/folders/protocol_channels/entry7909.aspx) website of using the [specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery).  I would recommend searching services based on scope, by probing for services based on a specific endpoint.

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is a way to auto discovery services. The .NET 4.0 includes a feature called WCF-Discovery its based on the WS-Discovery protocol. There is a training kit that shows a HOL here:
(http) [code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfwf4](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfwf4) 
You can also follow the team's blog here:
(http) [blogs.msdn.com/discovery/Default.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/discovery/Default.aspx)